# Help How to install HD5550 in xubuntu 13.04

Tags: xubuntu

How to install a ati hd5550 in xubuntu 13.04 please help

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want the open-source or proprietary drivers, for the latter this site is your best bet: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI